# IllegalArgumentException while using javax.sql.Datasource and hosting the application on Websphere

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting an "Illegal Argument Exception" when I try to use javax.sql.DataSource to execute a stored procedure from spring based application

The stack trace is as follows.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection() throws java.sql.SQLException] on target [com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@4582a8fc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy115.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1367)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1333)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    ... 56 more
```

The source code is as follows.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlTypeValue;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;


public class CERBulkUploadSP extends StoredProcedure{

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    public CERBulkUploadSP(DataSource dataSource, String storedProcName) {

        // Run the Parent
        super(dataSource, storedProcName);

        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("CERA Processes Stored Procedure Name : "+ storedProcName);
        }

        // Declare the Parameter Details
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("THE_ARRAY", Types.ARRAY, "CER.GL_ENTRY_TYPE_ARRAY"));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("INCIDENT_DIM_ID", Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("INS_USER", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("P_STATUS", Types.VARCHAR));

        // Compile the SP
        compile();
    }

    public boolean execute(final BaseViewBean baseViewBean$Session, final long incidentDimId, final String loginUser, final String identifier) throws Exception {

        boolean returnVal = false;
        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        log.info("Setting up the Stored Procedure Params");

        inParams.put("THE_ARRAY", new SqlTypeValue() {
            public void setTypeValue(PreparedStatement cs, int index, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
                Connection con = cs.getConnection();
                ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CER.GL_ENTRY_TYPE_ARRAY", con);
                ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, baseViewBean$Session.getExcelRecLst().toArray());
                cs.setObject(1, (Object)a);
            }
        });
        inParams.put("INCIDENT_DIM_ID", incidentDimId);
        inParams.put("INS_USER", loginUser);
        inParams.put("P_STATUS", identifier);

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Executing the CERA Stored Procedure ");
        }

        Map out = execute(inParams);

        log.info("output size is --------------------->>>>>>>>>> "+out.size());
        for(Object o : out.keySet()){
            log.info((String)out.get(o));
            returnVal = Boolean.parseBoolean((String)out.get(o));
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.info("Output from CERA Stored Procedure :" + out);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

bean definition is as follows.

```
<bean id="cerBulkUploadSp" class="com.****.CERBulkUploadSP">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="ceraDataSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <value>CER.GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES</value>
    </constructor-arg>      
</bean>

<bean id="processDao" class="com.****.ProcessDaoImpl">
        <property name="storedProcedure">
            <ref bean="cerBulkUploadSp"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" > <ref bean="ceraHibernateTemplate"/></property>
    </bean>
```

classpath:com/*****/hibernate

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource"> <ref bean="ceraDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

My JNDI configuration is as follows.

```
<bean id="ceraDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/CERDS</value>
    </property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="cache">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterface">
        <value>javax.sql.DataSource</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The jars in my classpath are as follows.

```
JaxrpcComponent300V5.jar                        
ajaxtags-1.2-beta3.jar                          
ajaxtags-1.3-beta-rc7.jar                       
antlr.jar                                       
aopalliance.jar                                 
asm-commons.jar                                 
asm-util.jar                                    
asm.jar                                         
aspectjrt.jar                                   
aspectjweaver.jar                               
bsf.jar                                         
castor-anttasks.jar                             
castor-codegen.jar                              
castor-xml.jar                                  
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar                           
classes12.jar                                   
commons-beanutils.jar                           
commons-chain.jar                               
commons-codec.jar                               
commons-collections.jar                         
commons-dbcp.jar                                
commons-digester.jar                            
commons-fileupload.jar                          
commons-httpclient.jar                          
commons-io.jar                                  
commons-jxpath.jar                              
commons-lang.jar                                
commons-logging.jar                             
commons-pool.jar                                
commons-validator.jar                           
displaytag-1.2.jar                              
displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar                   
displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar                      
dom4j-1.5.2.jar                                 
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                                 
ehcache.jar                                     
ejb3-persistence.jar                            
hibernate-annotations.jar                       
hibernate-entitymanager.jar                     
hibernate-validator.jar                         
hibernate3.jar                                  
ibatis.jar                                      
jakarta-oro.jar                                 
jamon.jar                                       
javassist.jar                                   
jaxb-api.jar                                    
jboss-archive-browsing.jar                      
jericho-html-2.4.jar                            
jsr173_1.0_api.jar                              
jta.jar                                         
juh-3.2.1.jar                                   
juh.jar                                         
jurt-3.2.1.jar                                  
jurt.jar                                        
list.txt                                        
log4j.jar                                       
mvel.jar                                        
poi-3.8-20120326.jar                            
poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar                   
poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar                      
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar              
poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar                 
psecWsClient500.jar                             
quartz-all.jar                                  
ridl.jar                                        
spring-agent.jar                                
spring-aop.jar                                  
spring-aspects.jar                              
spring-beans.jar                                
spring-context-support.jar                      
spring-context.jar                              
spring-core.jar                                 
spring-jdbc.jar                                 
spring-jms.jar                                  
spring-mock.jar                                 
spring-modules-validation.jar                   
spring-orm.jar                                  
spring-security-acl.jar                         
spring-security-catalina.jar                    
spring-security-core-tiger.jar                  
spring-security-core.jar                        
spring-security-ntlm.jar                        
spring-security-openid.jar                      
spring-security-portlet.jar                     
spring-security-taglibs.jar                     
spring-tomcat-weaver.jar                        
spring-tx.jar                                   
spring-web.jar                                  
spring-webmvc-portlet.jar                       
spring-webmvc-struts.jar                        
spring-webmvc.jar                               
struts-core.jar                                 
struts-el.jar                                   
struts-extras.jar                               
struts-faces.jar                                
struts-scripting.jar                            
struts-taglib.jar                               
struts-tiles.jar                                
unoil.jar                                       
unoloader.jar                                   
urlprocessingfilter300V5.jar                    
velocity.jar                                    
xbean.jar                                       
xerces-2.2.1.jar
```

When is run the app locally hosting it on tomcat and representing the datasource as oracle connection it works well, but when i deploy the code onto Websphere server where all our apps are hosted, i run into this problem. Can anyone please let me know how to resolve the same?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an ojdbc.jar on your classpath? (web-inf/lib?)

Comment: @abalogh - No, i do not have. I tried putting ojdbc14.jar, but had the same problem, so i got it removed.

Comment: @abalogh - I have updated my question with the list of jars that are present in my classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have old Oracle JDBC drivers in your classpath: `classes12.jar`. This is for [Oracle 10.2 and JDK 1.2/1.3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) - I doubt this is your environment. Possibly also other JARs might contain `javax.sql.*` classes (don't know them all).

Did you by any chance also switch the WebSphere  Classloader mode from PARENT_FIRST (default) to PARENT_LAST?

Comment: Tried everything, but no solution yet. Classloader is PARENT_LAST.

Comment: Everything? You deleted `classes12.jar`? You replaced it with a newer version that matches your environment? You switched back to PARENT_FIRST? You made sure no other JARs in your classpath contain `javax.sql` classes?

Comment: which is the newer version of classes12.jar? I am presently using oracle 10g and i also switched to PARENT_FIRST. It works like a charm on my Tomcat and when i mention thin driver, but doesn't when i deploy on websphere which makes use of JNDI.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar for JDK4/5 (see link in my answer). [ojdbc5/6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) for JDK5/6. JDBC drivers from 11g work with 10g. However, if you really include in your `WEB-INF/lib` (which you shouldn't if you use JNDI) it just has to match what the JNDI datasource is configured with.

Comment: i had tried puttin ojdbc14_g.jar as well. Still had the same issue.

Comment: Now i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection when the functionality is accessed.

Comment: Final Update - Got it working by changing the classloader to to PARENT_FIRST and also the below code change to get the native connection. Please note - The following piece of code is compatible on Websphere machines only.                                 OracleConnection con = (OracleConnection) WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection) dataSource.getConnection());